# Getting Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to do ssh to Google Cloud instance.I am able to do ssh to my username (lets say my pc user name is apple then I can access apple username) but when I am trying to access different username on same instance (lets say info) then its giving me "Permission Denied (public key)".

I am new bee in linux, please help me how I can access different username directory from my system.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thnx, I was not aware with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected, Linux users have their own user area commonly refer to as **Home**. Just like Windows user or Mac user, each user is separate and properties (files/folders) within one user cannot be directly accessed from another user without delegating that task to Superuser. In this case, you use `sudo` in front of the command to tell the system that you've right to access that resource using the powers of superuser.

#### To answer your question, you need to add your public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on all users that you wish to access over SSH (`ssh info@IP` or `ssh apple@IP`).

---

However, there is another approach to this, instead of adding your public key to a user belong to **sudoers** group or `root` user otherwise (NOT recommended to expose `root` user to outside for obvious security reasons). Then you just simply SSH into that user and run `sudo su - USERNAME` where **USERNAME** is any user in the system other than the current user (default is `root` so by running `sudo su -` you'll assume root user).

FYI, **-** in the middle tells the system to make the current directory of to the home directory of that user, if you leave the **-** out you'll still become that user but your current directory still be the same as where you ran the command.
This will ask you to enter the user password the first time you run a command with `sudo` prefix to authenticate that you are who you're not your friend or a hacker. You can stop this by changing the Sudoers file  with `sudo visudo` command (`visudo` for **root** user), this will give you a file that defines permissions. You can either allow all user in the **Sudoers** group by replacing the line begin with `%sudo` with following:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Or you can add line below the section ***# User privilege specification***

```
USERNAME   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Where **USERNAME** is the actual username, this will only allow that user to run `sudo` commands without a password prompt.

Hope this answers your question.